# Connecting to an external HTTP api behind a proxy from nifi

Tags: salesforce, apache-nifi, soql

I have a `apache/nifi:latest` instance spun inside an Amazon Linux 2 EC2.  For reference, see this guide: [here](https://medium.com/geekculture/host-a-fully-persisted-apache-nifi-service-with-docker-ffaa6a5f54a3)

I have a `QuerySalesforceObject` ver. `1.18.0` that makes use of StandardOauth2AccessTokenProvider.

[image: Salesforce Object]

The oauth2 provider url is configured at https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

[image: Oauth Image]

I can `curl` this url from the box and from inside the docker container just fine (I don’t get a timeout).

```
[root@ip-10-229-18-107 \~\]# docker exec -it nifi_container_persistent /bin/sh

printenv | grep -i proxy

HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.MY_DOMAIN.com:3128

no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,MY_DOMAIN.com,.amazonaws.com

NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1, MY_DOMAIN.com,.amazonaws.com

https_proxy=http://proxy.MY_DOMAIN.com:3128

http_proxy=http://proxy.MY_DOMAIN.com:3128

HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.MY_DOMAIN.com:3128

curl https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token

{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant type not supported"}#
```

But when I run the task, oauth2 fails with an error

```
java.io.UncheckedIOException: OAuth2 access token request failed

Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

[image: Error Message]

This leads me to believe the proxy settings are not being honored by the class.  How can I fix this?

Here’s more info on this class: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-oauth2-provider-nar/1.17.0/org.apache.nifi.oauth2.StandardOauth2AccessTokenProvider/index.html

Comment: Any update on if you got this working. I am facing a very similar issue on InvokeHTTP processor where the StandardOauth2AccessTokenProvider and StandardProxyConfigurationService have been configured. I can get the OAuth token using a curl command in ExecuteProcess using the same proxy config, but when everything is put together via InvokeHTTP, I get the same time out error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to interface with HTTP resources with a proxy in Nifi is via `StandardProxyConfigurationService`: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-proxy-configuration-nar/1.19.1/org.apache.nifi.proxy.StandardProxyConfigurationService/index.html

If a component does not have this property, then it means it does not support it.

You can try bootstrapping proxy settings into nifi with `/opt/nifi/nifi-current/conf/bootstrap.conf`.  But there is no standard and support of proxy is not guaranteed.  Implementation (bugs and all) depends on the library.  `aws-java-sdk` ver. 1x, for example, has a bug where `nonProxyHosts` is not honoured.  https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/issues/2797

```
java.arg.18=-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="foo|localhost|*.bar.org"
java.arg.19=-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.foo.com
java.arg.20=-Dhttp.proxyPort=123
java.arg.21=-Dhttp.proxyUser=foo
java.arg.22=-Dhttp.proxyPassword=bar

java.arg.23=-Dhttps.nonProxyHosts="foo|localhost|*.bar.org"
java.arg.24=-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.foo.com
java.arg.25=-Dhttps.proxyPort=123
java.arg.26=-Dhttps.proxyUser=foo
java.arg.27=-Dhttps.proxyPassword=bar
```